# Woocommerce `default_checkout_billing_country` filter set's the user's billing country in checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

User's billing country is setting to the country mentioned in  `default_checkout_billing_country` filter. Expected behaviour is to set to user's saved billing country instead of default country. This has been happening since the woocommerce 3.0 update.

Steps to produce :

1. Add `default_checkout_billing_country` filter in funcitons.php in your theme and set the country code which you want to be default.(Refer to [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/change-the-default-state-and-country-on-the-checkout/))
2. Edit the user's billing address from my account and set the country to some other country other than the default country mentioned above.
3. Now add a product to cart and go to checkout page.
4. The billing address country is being set to default country rather than user's biling country that has been saved.

Comment: Can you please show me the screen shot what you want?

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear what I want

Comment: Any one with the solution?? or is it a bug??